# Modifying WooCommerce Shortcode [products]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I need to modify the shortcode [products ids=...] of WooCommerce. I want to put a single "div" part while returning the product with every other asset that is originally returned. To be specific, I have a table that I store product ID's and their "scores". I want to show that particular product's score while when I use [products] shortcode. I know how to use $wpdb etc, but I don't know how to modify WooCommerce shortcode / couldn't find it.

Note: I know how to write my own shortcode, but I also want to add those scores to product archive pages which are originally created by WooCommerce. Is there any easy way to do that without losing the code on plugin updates? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own shortcode which utilizes WooCommerce's `[products]` shortcode.

Something like:

```php
add_shortcode( 'mc_products', 'mc_products_shortcode' );

/**
 * Add a custom 'mc_products' shortcode
 *
 * @param array $atts  Shortcode attributes
 * @return string
 */
function mc_products_shortcode( $atts) {
  // Pass whichever attributes you need to the 'products' shortcode
  return do_shortcode( "[products ids={$atts['ids']}]" );
}
```

Then, instead of `[products ids=…]` you would use `[mc_products ids=…]`

If for some reason you need to override the existing 'products' shortcode, you can remove it and then re-add it with your own implementation.

This would look like:

```php
remove_shortcode( 'products' );
add_shortcode( 'products', 'mc_products_shortcode' );

/**
 * Replace the existing 'product' shortcode with our own implementation
 *
 * @param array $atts  Shortcode attributes
 * @return string
 */
function mc_products_shortcode( $atts ) {
  // Add your own implementation of the 'products' shortcode
}
```

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I haven't tested this code, but hope you get the idea.</sub>

Comment: I think I can implement this easily, thank you! I have a simpler question, do you think it will also affect the product archive pages created by WC? Because my main motivation behind not creating my own shortcode was also showing these "scores" inside WC's product archive pages.

Comment: @MertCüceloğlu Happy to help! It looks like the WooCommerce 'products' shortcode uses `content-product.php`, so perhaps you can accomplish what you want by simply [hooking into one of its hooks](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/889cf64ac465826104080e5f8ce23e09109cf777/templates/content-product.php#L28-L65) to show your "scores", without even modifying any shortcodes.